# Add web services functionality to current working java application

Tags: java, web-services, web

I'm trying to create web services functionality linked to my current working java application and struggling to do it. Any ides ?

At line:

```
TopUpApp application = new TopUpApp();
```

I'm creating a new instance from the other class , but it doesn't seem to work when I test web service. Giving false as a return where it should be true.

Below is the code for web service.

```
package org.me;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

/**
 *
 * @author KS
 */
@WebService(serviceName = "DOAws")
@Stateless()
public class DOAws {

    /**
     * Web service operation
     */
    @WebMethod(operationName = "login")
    public boolean login(@WebParam(name = "username") int username, @WebParam(name = "password") String password) {
        TopUpApp application = new TopUpApp();
        return application.authenticate(username, password);
    }
}
```

It works fine and I get true as a response when I run it in new main class this way (not a web service):

```
public class NewClass {
    public static void main(String []args){
        TopUpApp application = new TopUpApp();

        System.out.println(application.authenticate(12345, "12345"));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To deploy your application as a web service, you need to do a little bit more than what is necessary for a normal java application.

I short, what you need to do is to deploy your application on a web server that is also able to deploy java web applications. Many such web servers exists, a couple of popular alternatives are [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/) and [Jetty](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jetty/).

The normal thing to do is to install the web server on the machine that is supposed to handle the requests. Next you need to deploy your application on that server. To do that, you will need to do a couple of things:

1. Package your application as a war (web archive). How to do this is quite straightforward, but involves a few steps. You should be able to figure this out by yourself using google.
2. Deploy your application to the web server. This is usually done by copying the war file to the web applications directory of your web server. E.g. the `webapps` directory under the tomcat installation directory.

When this is done, you just need to make sure that your web server is up and running, and you should be able to access your web services.

Comment: I'm using Glassfish as a webserver as it's built into Netbeans. I'm able to deploy the project to the server, but it doesn't seems to recognize any class outside the class which contains the web service. At the end I've managed to get the application working by copying all the classes into WebService class but it doesn't seem to be the best solution. Thanks